# Securely deploy public repo to remote VM from Travis CI?

Tags: javascript, git, encryption, continuous-integration, travis-ci

How do I securely deploy a **public** repository (*JavaScript application*) from Travis CI to a remote VM running `CentOS 6.5` ?

Had using a Jenkins server in the past a "central deployment server" - we would trade SSH keys between the Jenkins server and the VM being deployed to. This would allow us to **SCP the build** because it was nothing more then some JavaScript files.

If I wanted to deploy to that same VM from Travis CI - I'm having a time understanding how this would work purely from the `.travis.yml` file - if its at all possible.

There is some information here about [generating encryption keys](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/encryption-keys/) as well as a guide here about [encrypting sensitive files and data](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/travis-pro/#sts=How%20can%20I%20encrypt%20files%20that%20include%20sensitive%20data) but I just don't know where to start.

- Is this even possible to do securely with a public repository?
- Is there a better way to go about this or different service I should be using?
- How would I set up my `.travis.yml` file and `CentOS 6.5` VM to accomplish something like this?